# Azure DevOps yaml dependency

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, devops

I have a problem with dependency on yaml. When I cancel the previous stage I want my next stage not to execute. The problem is with the or() and() part. When I add succeeded() to and() part it is working fine but it has to work on the second or() condition. Unfortunately when I add succeeded() to or() part it is not working as expected. The below code is not working, when I cancel the previous stage this one executes ?

```
dependsOn: 'CI'
  condition: or(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'), eq('${{ parameters.devEnvironment }}', 'dev'), and(eq('${{ parameters.devEnvironment }}', 'dev'), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'),succeeded()))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I cancel the previous stage I want my next stage not to execute.

What you need to do is to use `and()` condition to connect your original conditions and `suceeded()`:

```
condition: and({original condition}, succeeded())
```

Here is the exmaple:

```
condition: and(or(ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'), eq('${{ parameters.devEnvironment }}', 'dev'), and(eq('${{ parameters.devEnvironment }}', 'dev'), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')), succeeded())
```